# Calling a rest webservice from html..Passing in credentials

Tags: java, html, ajax, web-services, jakarta-ee

When a html page makes a call to a rest webservice, how can the service credentials be sent in the request?

The username and pwd needed by the service can be sent in the request itself by using (usename:pwd@service.com) notation, but that would not be wise sending in the creds in the request itself.

Any other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: If it's basic auth you send them in the http header.

Answer (score 0):

If it uses BASIC authentication, it is sent along the request as a header (in clear).  Have a look at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

This can be hardened by using a secure protocol (https), with which you encode your request (basic authentication included).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure

This requires additional configuration on the server-side

Comment: Jorge..am i right when I say that if the service url is "http", then it is basic authentication...and if it is "https" it is secure authentication ?

Comment: Sorry not.  Both can require basic authentication of the client (in that case, the browser should present you some graphic way to introduce name and password), but only https would encrypt your request before sending it.